# How should I rid of a 3 second delay when rendering react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies in advance, but I am currently a beginner with React.

I am currently working on a toggle button, but the action of toggling the button seems to not be instant, rather taking around 3 seconds. I have tried to ask people online, but so far I am still not sure why this seems to be the case.

Index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import * as resources from 'home/resources/settings/utility';
import View from './View';

class SettingsUtility extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      busy: true,
      value: false,
      tempValue: false,
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // delay to avoid 401 since this loads user at the same time with
    // global user loading
    setTimeout(() => {
      resources.load().then(response => {
        this.setState({ busy: false, value: response, tempValue: response });
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  toggle() {
    if (this.state.busy) { return; }
    const tempValue = !this.state.tempValue;
    this.setState({ busy: true, tempValue });
    resources.update(tempValue)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          busy: false,
          value: response,
          tempValue: response,
        });
      }).catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          busy: false,
          tempValue: !tempValue,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View {...this.props} {...this.state} toggle={this.toggle} />
    );
  }
}

export default SettingsUtility;
```

View.jsx

```
import T from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import Toggle from 'core/components/Input/Toggle';
import Hint from 'core/components/Hint';

import translate from './translate';
import s from '../styles.css';

const SettingsUtilityView = ({ id, busy, value, tempValue, toggle }) => (
  <div className={s.item}>
    <h4>{translate('header')}</h4>
    <p className={s.content}>
      {translate('message')}
      <Hint hint={translate('hint')} />
    </p>
    <p className={s.content}>
      {translate('note')}
    </p>
    <div>
      <Toggle id={`${id}--daily`} value={tempValue} onChange={toggle} busy={busy} />
      <span className={s.toggleText}>
        {value ? translate('on') : translate('off')}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
);

SettingsUtilityView.propTypes = {
  id: T.string.isRequired,
  busy: T.bool.isRequired,
  value: T.bool.isRequired,
  tempValue: T.bool.isRequired,
  toggle: T.func.isRequired,
};

export default SettingsUtilityView;
```

I dont think there are any issues with the css that will have any effect, but could the code be more efficient?

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried profiling in chrome to see if some part of the code eating up too much time?

Answer (score 0):

In `componentDidMount` you are setting a timeout of 2 seconds, which loads some resources. After that the state property `busy` is set to `false` which enables you to use the `toggle` function. This is because `toggle` will always return while busy (see first line of `toggle` method).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there should not be any ***setTimeout function***, and if possible handle your response with proper *fallback condition* so that there will be no any key or console error.

And in that case you can use *loader till your response* come. And once your response came disable your loader.

code:

```
       componentWillMount() {
               this.setState({pageLoader: true})
               resources.load().then(response => {
                this.setState({ busy: false, value: response, tempValue: response },
()=>{this.setState({pageLoader: false})});
              });
            };
```